# unable to fetch images in image slider in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I extend an `Activity` this works fine, but when extending `ActivityFragment` I get an error:

> unable to resolve constructor

At this line: `BaseViewPagerAdapter<String> adapter = new BaseViewPagerAdapter<String>(this)`.  I'm just fetching the image from a URL and displaying it in an image slider. If anyone knows any links or tutorials feel free to suggest me. Thanks.

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment {
private String[] paths = {"http://reviewsimpact.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Patanjali-products-list-1024x385.png",
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3-qgzGwoQ3o/Vuqb1a0g6RI/AAAAAAAAATc/FZjOTm0VUBgXsw3VnWz3RorARUUUgl32g/s1600/Baba%2BRamdev%2BPatanjali%2BProducts%2BList%2Bwith%2BPrice%2Blatest%2B-%2BTipsmonk.jpg",
        "http://patanjalistores.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/maxresdefault-1920x692.jpg",
        "https://aos.iacpublishinglabs.com/question/aq/700px-394px/poems-fruits-vegetables_8d6a91e11da7d63.jpg?domain=cx.aos.ask.com",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2IVR8BrUESQ/maxresdefault.jpg"};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    AutoScrollViewPager mViewPager = (AutoScrollViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager = (AutoScrollViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    BaseViewPagerAdapter<String> adapter = new BaseViewPagerAdapter<String>(this) {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(ImageView view, int position, String url) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSubTitle(TextView textView, int position, String s) {
            textView.setText("");
        }
    };
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.add(initData());


    return v;

}
private List<String> initData() {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Picture picture ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < paths.length ;i++){
        data.add(paths[i]);
    }
    return data;
}

}
```

BaseBaseViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public abstract class BaseViewPagerAdapter<T> extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

private List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();

private Context mContext;
private AutoViewPager mView;

private OnAutoViewPagerItemClickListener listener;

public BaseViewPagerAdapter(List<T> t) {
    this.data = t;
}



public BaseViewPagerAdapter(Context context, OnAutoViewPagerItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

public BaseViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<T> data) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.data = data;
}

public BaseViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<T> data,OnAutoViewPagerItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.listener = listener;
}



public void init(AutoViewPager viewPager,BaseViewPagerAdapter adapter){
    mView = viewPager;
    mView.setAdapter(this);
    mView.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    if (data == null || data.size() == 0){
        return;
    }
    //设置初始为中间，这样一开始就能够往左滑动了
    int position = Integer.MAX_VALUE/2 - (Integer.MAX_VALUE/2) % getRealCount();
    mView.setCurrentItem(position);

    if (!mView.isStart()) {
        mView.start();
        mView.updatePointView(getRealCount());
    }

}

public void setListener(OnAutoViewPagerItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void add(T t){
    data.add(t);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    mView.updatePointView(getRealCount());
}

public void add(List<T> list){
    if (data == null) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    data.addAll(list);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    mView.start();
    mView.updatePointView(getRealCount());

}

public void init(List<T> list){
    if (data == null) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    data.clear();
    data.addAll(list);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (!mView.isStart()) {
        mView.start();
        mView.updatePointView(getRealCount());
    }


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (data == null || data.size() == 0 ) ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

public int getRealCount(){
    return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.imageview,container,false);
    loadImage(view,position, data.get(position % getRealCount()));
    container.addView(view);

    //设置标题(不知道为什么标题跟图片对不上，所以做了如下处理，有大神看到帮忙看看。。。)
    if (mView.getSubTitle() != null){
        if (position == 0){
            setSubTitle(mView.getSubTitle(),position,data.get((getRealCount() - 1)));
        }else {
            setSubTitle(mView.getSubTitle(),position,data.get((position - 1) % getRealCount()));
        }

    }

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(position % getRealCount(),data.get(position % getRealCount()));
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public abstract void loadImage(ImageView view,int position,T t);
public abstract void setSubTitle(TextView textView,int position,T t);

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mView.onPageSelected(position % getRealCount());
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

public interface OnAutoViewPagerItemClickListener<T> {
    void onItemClick(int position,T t);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);



    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navigation_drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeActivity();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure you need to instantiate BaseViewPagerAdapter? I dont see a constructor which takes only context and also it is an abstract class...

Comment: Yes. Do u know any tutorial in which fetching of images is done in image slider in fragments??

Comment: none i can think of..if I have to search it will be in google anyway

Comment: Can i have u email id for discussion?

Comment: Also i m searching alot i didnt get in google even i search for video but didnot find it